# Tomcat doesn't invalidates session after calling session.invalidate()

Tags: web-services, session, tomcat, invalidation

I have a webservice in jaxws to which I can connect after login. Everything works perfectly, I pass login and password and I'm logged in, and I'm creating session for this user on WS server. After all I want to logout, so I delete all session attributes and I call session.invalidate().

Attributes are removed, but when I enter to the tomcat manager, I see that the session is still there.

When I was logged in, session had set setMaxInactiveInterval to 7200 s (2hours). Session will be destroyed after this time of course, but if that session is not used anymore, what is the sense to keep empty session alive for 2 hours.

Is there a way to destroy that session completly? Without waiting 2 hours?

Comment: So you have some kind of "logout" web service request? You shouldn't have to delete the session attributes: if you invalidate the session, that should be done for you. Do you have any HttpSessionListener or HttpSessionBindingListener objects registered? If so, they may be interfering with Tomcat's ability to actually expire your session. You do not have to wait 2 hours.

Comment: I don't have any of those two listeners registered. Yes it's some kind of logout. I know that I shouldn't have to wait 2 hourse, but still, session is active. I will remove part with which removes attributes from session.

Comment: Currently in disconnect() method I have session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1) and the session is destroyed after 30s - 1min, It's better then 2 hours but I'm sure that's bad solution. If I will add the session.invalidate() to this method, the session will expire after 30 minutes. I don't know why it's happening, Session should be destroyed, but it's not :/

Comment: On which OS it is happening? For me session.invalidate() not working in Centos OS, but the same is perfectly fine in Windows.

Comment: See: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html as mentioned by: http://serverfault.com/questions/300222/invalidate-all-sessions-at-application-reload

Answer (score 0):

Try these in your Response

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

To make sure subsecquent requests shouldn't re-instantiate your session.

Comment: Yes, but it's web service so really I don't know where to place that? On the client side or server side? How can I get reference to the response object?

Comment: server side, and are you not talking about HttpSession ?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about HttpSession but on web service. I'm using this solution for maintaing session: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2006/06/maintaining_ses.html .

Comment: This answer is entirely useless and has nothing to do with `HttpSession`.